# Corrupted AVI Raw files

Tags: rendering, animation, video

I am experiencing an issue, when I choose to render an animation to AVI Raw from Blender. I can not play the video properly, the video file seems to be corrupted. The rendered file has around 5 GB, quite big actually.

The default video player in Windows 10 plays only the first few seconds of the animation. Then the video ends without reporting any errors.

On the other hand, VLC detects the error and offers a solution. The file is obviously missing an `Index`. Unfortunately, this workaround fixes the file only temporarily to play. So, is there any way how to generate the `Index` for the file? Even Adobe Premiere Pro cannot import this file.

[image: VLC report]

Render settings of the animation in Blender

[image: Render settings in Blender]

Thank you for the answers in advance.

Comment: render as an image sequence and encode to ffmpeg later. if you choose to use premiere instead of blender vse for encoding  then premiere can read tif sequences from blender just fine.

Comment: What is your goal? Just to play back the file or are you doing further post processing? Why do you need RAW? AVI Raw is an inefficeint format with huge files that are most likely unplayable by most computers. As recommended on the previous comment, render as images and encode to a format that is designed for efficient playback.

Comment: Sure, rendering the animation to the image sequence is a solution, but it adds extra work. I want to save the animation to AVI Raw, because it uses lossless compression. And it is much more handy and convenient for me, so I can easily edit it in Adobe Premiere Pro. My goal is to make animated scenes for a YouTube video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I solved the problem by dividing the animation into pieces and gradually rendering these parts. Then I will just grab these pieces in Adobe Premiere Pro and join them together.

When you search for maximum size of AVI, it outputs 2 GB. That's most likely why the files above this limit are corrupted.

[image: Blender animation length]

Comment: There is a good reason why you will not see AVI files in any profesional workflow. If you want smaller files with perfect quality use EXR. Or if you must use a video format use QuickTime DNxHD

Comment: Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Open using VLC and chose option "(corrupted) Index reconstruction", and avi file works fine again.

Comment: I tried this back then, but as of I remember, I still could not use the file in other programs.